# How to reference a ng-template from inside a div?

Tags: angular, ng-template

My ng-containers are inside a div and so I can't access the ng-template. Is there a way to do this?

```
<div>     
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
</div>

<div>     
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #myTemplate></ng-template>
```

Comment: Are you importing CommonModule in your NgModule?

Comment: @DavideBellone I have imported the BrowserModule in NgModule. That should be the same

Comment: Yes, you can do this. What do you mean by "can't access the ng-template"?

Comment: Your code works fine, check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvyswb). Is there anything else you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work fine, if you want to pass in a context you can use [`ngTemplateOutletContext`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description) like this:

```
<div>     
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate; context: context1"></ng-container>
</div>

<div>     
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate; context: context2"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template let-person #myTemplate>
  Template goes here
  {{person.name}}
</ng-template>
```

---

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  context1 = {$implicit: {name: 'Marcos'}};
  context2 = {$implicit: {name: 'Beccari'}};
}
```

---

Check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvyswb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)